# Likelihood test for normal data coming from a block diagonal covariance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, inference

I have data **known** to be coming from a normal distribution with a block diagonal covariance matrix.

I've seen various tests for determining whether the covariance is block diagonal, so I guess it has some uses.

Does it mean that statistical tests can be performed independently on each features group? What can we benefit from the block diagonal structure? I would appreciate some references.

Thanks.